# how can i put date and time picker in a dialog in android

Tags: android, dialog, datetimepicker

i an new in android and struggling with how can i add these two `date picker` and `time picker` in a single `dialog box` please guide me how can i do it i created a `dialog box` and use a function `setview` to inflate it but i got the exception

```
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Begning");
            dialog.setPositiveButton("ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
             View pickers=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.linearLayout1,
             null);
            dialog.setView(picker);

            dialog.show();

        }
    });
```

above is my code
and hear is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<DatePicker
     android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</DatePicker>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</TimePicker>
```

[image]

i want to create something like this please help me

```
    10-06 15:49:24.261: E/Trace(9287): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-06 15:49:27.434: W/dalvikvm(9287): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411903a8)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080000 type #0x12 is not valid
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2150)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:860)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at com.example.datetimedialog.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1058)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:825)
10-06 15:49:27.454: E/AndroidRuntime(9287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the `logcat` which i got while running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a project on github for this. I have taken a different approach than yours and have created the custom dialog with date and time picker, by extending the dialog class.

https://github.com/ramesh130/DateTimePickerDialog

Comment: Thankyou very much @ramesh can't tell you how much happy i am, you are awesome buddy, i have serached almost every page but not found it

Comment: as you have used Dialog Fragment which need support library to run for API level 9, is there any alternative way, if we don't want to use support library ?please suggest

Comment: You can use compatibility package...however the code doesnt depend on the fragments, you can replace it with activity without any issues...

Comment: I need to increment the minute interval with 15 minutes and also need to support it with API 9 and above. Which should display the native Date Time picker. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use R.layout.linearLayout1,not R.id.linearLayout1,like this:

```
View pickers=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linearLayout1,null);
```

assuming the name of your layout file is `linearLayout1`.